# WPF download image bytes from Blob Storage

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to preload a lot of images when my app starts up, sort of a once off thing.

I have an `Image` class that contains the Url of its image stored in the cloud as blob storage (this address is a **https** address BTW)

I want to download the image bytes from the cloud, store them on the object, then when it comes time to show the image, load the image from its bytes.

I have all the code for this, but I keep getting the exception:

**No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.**

Here is my code: **EDIT UPDATED WITH A FIX**

```
    //Loaded on start-up
    private static void LoadImageBytes(Image img)
    {
        var urlUri = new Uri(img.Url);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(urlUri);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4096];
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }

                img.ImageBytes = memStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then when I want to get the image on the screen I call this:

```
    public BitmapImage ImageFromBuffer(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = stream;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
```

But in the **EndInit()** call I get the exception.

I have done some testing and if I load the file from my local filesystem, I get a different set of bytes to that of the image in the cloud. I assume its something to do with blob storage or https?

*And yes I can browse to that image and its not corrupted.*

**EDIT, fixed now all good**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this line is correct?

```
 while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
                img.ImageBytes = buffer;
```

img.ImageBytes will hold the last read buffer.